# Sublime Text 3 Python 3 print while running

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I can't get Python 3 to print out anything while running a script in Sublime Text. I can get it to print out after the script has finished, but I need it to print as it goes.

Here's some example code

```
import time

    for x in range(10):
        print("Test")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Using Python 3 as the build system, I get nothing for 10 seconds, and then 10 "Tests" printed all at once.

If I run the same script using the Python 2 build system, I get 1 "Test" printed out each second, which is what I want.

Similarly if I run the script using "python3 script.py" in the terminal I get 1 "Test" printed out each second.

Can anyone tell me how to make the build system in Sublime Text 3 print out Python 3 while it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open your Python 3 build system configuration file, and ensure that the `-u` option is supplied to the command line to be executed.

For example:

```
# ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3.5", "-u", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u):

> #### -u
>
> Force the binary layer of the stdout and stderr streams (which is
>   available as their buffer attribute) to be unbuffered. The text I/O
>   layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console, or
>   block-buffered if redirected to a non-interactive file.

With this option, the ouptut of your Python script will be correctly displayed into Sublime Text while running.